# Javascript if-else statement not working

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm learning Javascript but having trouble running if else statements inside a function.

```js
var a = function(){
    console.log('fn starts');
    var b = 1;
    for (var i = 0; i <3; i++) {
        if(b=1){
            b+=1;
            console.log("if"+i);
        } else {
            console.log("else"+i);
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" onclick="a()"></div>
```

This code returns:
if0
if1
if2

While I expect it to expect b to increase in value everytime the if statement runs, it doesn't. What am I missing?

Comment: Should be `b==1`

Comment: `b=1` should be `b===1`. `=` assignment. `==` or `===`  comparison

Comment: if (b == 1) ...

Comment: Oh my god! Such a lame mistake. I can't believe I spent last 30 mins on this. Thanks guys!

Comment: @AkshayGupta Though I do not have any rights to do this, but I'd request you to remove this post once all the answers are removed. This is a very basic problem and will not add much to portal.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about removing it too

Comment: I'm trying to delete this question but it doesn't seem to work! Any suggestions?

Comment: @AkshayGupta You cannot delete a question if there is an answer on it.

Answer (score 0):

Give `==` instead of `=`

```js
var a = function(){
    console.log('fn starts');
    var b = 1;
    for (var i = 0; i <3; i++) {
        if(b==1){// must be double equal to
            b+=1;
            console.log("if"+i);
        } else {
            console.log("else"+i);
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" onclick="a()"></div>
```

Comment: Please note, not to answer such basic question. A comment is more that enough

Comment: Give downvote for the question, not for the answers

Comment: Downvote to an answer means either its incorrect or its **not required**.

Comment: @Rajesh and this not deserve to put -1 according to you -_- !!

Comment: @mir i don't think I owe you any more explanation. And as for your information, i downvoted this as well. It's just that someone else upvoted it. Also reps are off no use in real life. So please stop playing these dirty games.

Comment: @Rajesh If you hold your mouse over "add a comment"  it shows the following text  "Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid answering questions in comments." and this is what im talking about

Answer (score 0):

The conditional operator you are using is incorrect.

```
b=1;
```

above statement will assign the value 1 to the variable `b`.
If you want to compare the values you should use `==` opearator like this.

```
if(b==1)
```

Also you need to understand the difference between `==` and `===`.

`==` operator will simply compare the values. like 
if you check

```
if(1 == "1")
```

Above condition will return true but if you want to compare the datatype of the values as well you should use `===` like this

```
if(1 === "1"){  
   // false condition
} 
else {
 // this part will be executed in this condition,
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For equality check use `===` operator like

```
If (b === 1) {...}
```

Read about what does == and === operators mean

Comment: Please note, not to answer such basic question. A comment is more that enough

Comment: @Rajesh  yes but thats not deserve to put -1 to all because i have not  seen your answer in comment!!

Comment: @mir Please check comments under question. Also -1 means answer is **Not Required**. Its bad practice to answer this basic questions.

Comment: @Rajesh, i use comments to clarify or if i am not sure about question or answer, here question is asked and i know exact answer, and ryping over mobile phone, did not see any other comments or answers, do i deserve downvoting?

Comment: @Rajesh there is already one that has answered so you do not need to answer anyways thats not deserve to put -1.

Comment: @jhan I am in the some case

Comment: @jhan apologies if I offended you in any manner. To clarify, when you answer this basic question, it promotes spoon feeding as a simple google search would solve the issue. Hence answering such question is not promoted. Now downvote does not only mean your answer is wrong. It also mean its **not required**. And deleting your answer will revert any rep loss.

Comment: @mir I don't play such petty games so I'd request you to mind the tone. I have already clarified the reasons for downvotes. If you are not satisfied, i cannot help you.

Comment: @Rajesh i dis not get offended, unfair to put -1 to all who just wanted to help guy. It is not anout how much the question estimated for. Dev might already know this, but we just pointed where he has problem.

Comment: @jhan I'm aware about your intentions and I'm not doubting them, but a user should also learn on their own. This is a mistake that is even answered in textbooks. If then you make mistake, help them via comment. but adding an answer is just **wrong**.

Comment: @Rajesh we make downvote when the answer is not useful and not when its not required and the answer of all others is useful

Answer (score -2):

to test equals of number you should use == operation

```
var a = function(){
        console.log('fn starts');
        var b = 1;
        for (var i = 0; i <3; i++) {
            if(b==1){
                b+=1;
                console.log("if"+i);
            } else {
                console.log("else"+i);
            }
        }
    }
```